# Losing data when rendering rowchart using dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I lose data when creating a dc.js rowchart.

```
  var ndx = crossfilter(data);

  var emailDimemsion = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.email;
  });

  var emailGroup = emailDimemsion.group().reduce(
    function(p, d) {
      ++p.count;
      p.totalWordCount += +d.word_count;
      p.studentName = d.student_name;
      return p;
    },
    function(p, d) {
      --p.count;
      p.totalWordCount -= +d.word_count;
      p.studentName = d.student_name;
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return {
        count: 0,
        totalWordCount: 0,
        studentName: ""
      };
    });


  leaderRowChart
    .width(600)
    .height(300)
    .margins({
      top: 0,
      right: 10,
      bottom: 20,
      left: 5
    })
    .dimension(emailDimemsion)
    .group(emailGroup)
    .elasticX(true)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      return +d.value.totalWordCount;
    })
    .rowsCap(15)
    .othersGrouper(false)
    .label(function(d) {
      return (d.value.studentName + ": " + d.value.totalWordCount);
    })
    .ordering(function(d) {
      return -d.value.totalWordCount
    })
    .xAxis()
    .ticks(5);

  dc.renderAll();
```

The fiddle is here, https://jsfiddle.net/santoshsewlal/6vt8t8rn/

My graph comes out like this:
[image]

but I'm expecting my results to be

[image]

Have I messed up the reduce functions somehow to omit data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there are two levels of ordering for dc.js charts using crossfilter.

First, dc.js pulls the top N using `group.top(N)`, where N is the `rowsCap` value. Crossfilter sorts these items according to the [`group.order` function](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order).

Then it sorts the items again using the `chart.ordering` function.

In cases like these, the second sort can mask the fact that the first sort didn't work right. Crossfilter does not know how to sort objects unless you tell it what field to look at, so `group.top(N)` returns some random items instead.

You can fix your chart by making the crossfilter group's `order` match the chart's `ordering`:

```
emailGroup.order(function(p) {
  return p.totalWordCount;
})
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0kvatrb1/1/

It looks there is one student with a much longer word count, but otherwise this is consistent with your spreadsheet:

[image: fixed row chart]

We plan to stop using `group.top` in the future, because the current behavior is highly inconsistent.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/934

**Update**: If you're willing to use the unstable latest version, dc.js 2.1.4 and up do not use `group.top` - the capping is determined by `chart.ordering`, [capMixin.cap](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.capMixin.html#cap), and [capMixin.takeFront](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.capMixin.html#takeFront) only.

Comment: Is there a work-around for this behaviour?  The problem is that I need to use a fake group to display sub-sets of data based on a category.  My fiddle shows the difference when using the regular group and fake group, https://jsfiddle.net/santoshsewlal/tmqwvxee/.  It's not a consistent problem; selecting February from the drop down is fine but December isn't.

I'd like to end up with a chart per category (dtype in the fiddle).  Is there a better way to render my charts?

Comment: @SantoshSewlal, I've clarified the fix provided above. See also the note about the latest version.